# How to find where the request to AWS Secret Manager happens?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, aws-secrets-manager

My team uses AWS for my back-end app, and for storing configs we have AWS Secrets Manager. Recently, the number of requests to the SM dramatically increased (~45kk for 2 weeks). There were a lot of changes and I can't find the place in the code where we make such requests. Is there a way to log each time our server makes a request to Secrets Manager or find another way to solve the issue?
The back-end is written on asp.net c#.

Comment: Does the application code integrate with Secrets Manager?

Comment: Yes, and the logic of usage wasn't changed for ages. So, I am really puzzled with that